# Vanila JavaScript problem with setInterval and clearInterval

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a simple multiplication game using pure Javascript. When I click start button it calls a function  timeCalc(). The timeCalc function declares a variable name fullTime with the value of 7 and sets interval and after every second fullTime is decreasing by 1. when it decreases to 1 it sets the fullTime value to 7.

If I click on the start button many times the fullTime decreses so fast and in a disorder way even If I have done clearInterval() at the begining. I want to decrese the fullTime from 7 in a normal way even if I click it many times. what happens behind the scene?

Here is my code snippet. Thank you.

```js
const timeContainer = document.querySelector('.math__time');
const startBtn = document.querySelector('.math__start');

function timeCalc() {
  clearInterval(timeLeft);

  let fullTime = 7;
  timeContainer.textContent = fullTime;

  var timeLeft = setInterval(function() {
    fullTime--;
    timeContainer.textContent = fullTime;

    if (fullTime === 1) {
      fullTime = 7;
    }
  },1000);
}


startBtn.addEventListener('click', timeCalc);
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.math {
  background: gray;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

.math__calc {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.math__num {
  margin: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.math__num--wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.math__time {
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border: #fff 2px solid;
}
 

.math__start {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.math__multiply--symbol {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Math</title>
  <!-- default css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

</head>

<body class="math">
  <div class="math__time">0</div>
  <button class="math__start">Start</button>
  
  <div class="math__calc">
    <div class="math__num--wrapper">
      <div class="math__num math__num--one">88</div>
      <span class="math__multiply--symbol">*</span>
      <div class="math__num math__num--two">22</div>
    </div>
    <form class="math__ans">
      <input type="text" name="answer" class="math__ans--user">
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maheer is right, only addition would be to not pollute your global space. Create a closure to hold these variables. I updated the function to return a function.

**The problem**

Your `clearInterval(timeLeft)` is actually not clearing anything. The `timeLeft` is undefined at the moment of clearing.

**The Solution**

Moving your `timeleft`is in a higher scope. You can either:
- Put it in the global namespace (Not recommended)
- Create a scope around the timeCalc function.

I implemented the second solution below. I first changed the `timeCalc()`. Now the `timeCalc()` produces a function. This function can be used as the callback in for the `.addEventListener()`.

Then calling that function in the `.addEventListener()` will return a timer function with variables enclosed in a closure. I also changed the `fulltime` in the function to 8 to show 7 seconds after the countdown reached 1.

```js
const timeContainer = document.querySelector('.math__time');
const startBtn = document.querySelector('.math__start');

function timeCalc() {
  let timeLeft = null;
  let fullTime = 7;

  return function() {      
  clearInterval(timeLeft);
  fullTime = 7;
  timeContainer.textContent = fullTime;

  timeLeft = setInterval(function() {
    fullTime--;
    timeContainer.textContent = fullTime;

    if (fullTime === 1) {
      fullTime = 8;
    }
  },1000);
}
}


startBtn.addEventListener('click', timeCalc());
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.math {
  background: gray;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

.math__calc {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.math__num {
  margin: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.math__num--wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.math__time {
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border: #fff 2px solid;
}
 

.math__start {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.math__multiply--symbol {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Math</title>
  <!-- default css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

</head>

<body class="math">
  <div class="math__time">0</div>
  <button class="math__start">Start</button>
  
  <div class="math__calc">
    <div class="math__num--wrapper">
      <div class="math__num math__num--one">88</div>
      <span class="math__multiply--symbol">*</span>
      <div class="math__num math__num--two">22</div>
    </div>
    <form class="math__ans">
      <input type="text" name="answer" class="math__ans--user">
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What was happening inside the timeCalc() function before it was solved ? why that problem was occurring ? And now why do we need to add parenthesis in .addEventListener at the time of calling function ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `timeLeft` in global scope and change it inside function

```js
const timeContainer = document.querySelector('.math__time');
const startBtn = document.querySelector('.math__start');
let timeLeft;
let fullTime;
function timeCalc() {
  clearInterval(timeLeft);

  fullTime = 7;
  timeContainer.textContent = fullTime;

  timeLeft = setInterval(function() {
    fullTime--;
    timeContainer.textContent = fullTime;

    if (fullTime === 1) {
      fullTime = 8
    }
  },1000);
}


startBtn.addEventListener('click', timeCalc);
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.math {
  background: gray;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

.math__calc {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.math__num {
  margin: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.math__num--wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.math__time {
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border: #fff 2px solid;
}
 

.math__start {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.math__multiply--symbol {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Math</title>
  <!-- default css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

</head>

<body class="math">
  <div class="math__time">0</div>
  <button class="math__start">Start</button>
  
  <div class="math__calc">
    <div class="math__num--wrapper">
      <div class="math__num math__num--one">88</div>
      <span class="math__multiply--symbol">*</span>
      <div class="math__num math__num--two">22</div>
    </div>
    <form class="math__ans">
      <input type="text" name="answer" class="math__ans--user">
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```